# How to pass information to the stripe.checkout.sessions.create() function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

What I want to do:
I use firebase so as soon as someone purchases a Product over stripe I want to write that on the document of the user that bought it.
I want to use a stripe webhook for that. This webhook looks like this:

[image]

It essentially makes a https request to firebase functions as soon as the payment went trough. It triggers a https function that should write to the user's document that he has purchased the product. But to do that the webhook needs to contain the firebase user uid of the user that bought the product.

But to pass the user uid to the webhook I need to pass it to the stripe.checkout.sessions.create() function that looks like this:

```
    exports.createCheckoutSession = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
    const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:4242';
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items: [{
            price_data: {
                currency: 'usd',
                product_data: {
                    name: 'Stubborn Attachments',
                    images: ['https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png'],
                },
                unit_amount: 2000,
            },
            quantity: 1,
        }, ],
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/success.html`,
        cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/cancel.html`,
    });
    console.log(session.id)
    return session.id
})
```

(the user calls this cloud function to get a checkout session returned)
But how can I pass the user uid (`context.user.uid`) in so I can later send it with the webhook.

I hope it is clear what I want to do if not please ask. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Firebase UID of user or any other information in metadata of stripe checkout session like this:

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        // line items and other stuff
        metadata: {firebaseUID: uid, product_id: "ProductID"},
    });
```

You can read them in the checkout session completed webhook or any success webhook.

Comment: I get this error: `stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_Gqmo1HoMRF7GgE: Invalid object` when adding the line metadatawith this value: `{'items': {'id': 1, 'quantity': 2}}`

Comment: @rever I'm not sure what object you are trying to add. I'd recommend asking a new question as this seems to be a different issue.

Comment: ok I solved using an object with only simple data inside it, nested objects doesn't work. my purpose is to pass the id of the buyed items to update my database so I'll flat the array like: `{'items':2, 'id0':1, 'id1':2}`

Comment: @rever just found that in the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata). The metadata can have key-value pairs only.  Also you can specify up to 50 keys, with key names up to 40 characters long and values up to 500 characters long.